# How to retain the dropdown selection after adding new rows or columns to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a project requirement where I need to create a dynamic table using jQuery.
I have reached a state where I am able to add dynamic columns or rows to a table.
You can have a look at the fiddle code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rush2ashu/rwacv5mn/).

HTML:

```
<div id='input_div' name='input_div'>
Please Input your Matrix Dimensions : <input type="text" id="rowcount" size="2" value="2"> 
<span>X <input type="text" id="columncount" size ="2" value="2">
</div> <br><br>
<input type="button" id="tablebtn" value="Create Table">
<input type="button" id="newabilitybtn" value="Add Ability">
<input type="button" id="newlevelbtn" value="Add Level">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
<input type="button" class="addButton" value="Add" />
<br><br>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
var arr = [
  {val : 1, text: 'One'},
  {val : 2, text: 'Two'},
  {val : 3, text: 'Three'},
  {val : 4, text: 'Four'}
];
$("#newabilitybtn").hide();
$("#newlevelbtn").hide();
$("#submit").hide();

$("#tablebtn").click(function(){     
    mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "MatrixTable" });
    var rows = new Number($("#rowcount").val());
    var cols = new Number($("#columncount").val());
    var tr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            var td = $('<td>').appendTo(row);
            var sel = $('<select>').attr({ class: ["matrix"]  }).appendTo(td);
            $(arr).each(function() {
                sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
            });   
            $('</td>').appendTo(row);
        }   
        $('</tr>').appendTo(row);
    }
    console.log("TTTTT:"+mytable.html());
    mytable.appendTo("#box");   
    $("#tablebtn").hide(); $("#input_div").hide();
    $("#newabilitybtn").show();
    $("#newlevelbtn").show();
    $("#submit").show();
});

$("#newabilitybtn").click(function(){    
    var rows = $('#MatrixTable tr').length;
    var cols = $('#MatrixTable').find("tr:first td").length;
    var tr = []; 
    $('#MatrixTable').remove();
    mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "MatrixTable" });
    for (var i = 0; i < rows+1; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);

        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            var td = $('<td>').appendTo(row);
            var sel = $('<select>').attr({ class: ["matrix"]  }).appendTo(td); 
            $(arr).each(function() {
                sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
            });   
            $('</td>').appendTo(row);
        }
         $('</tr>').appendTo(row);

    }
    console.log("TTTTT:"+mytable.html());
    mytable.appendTo("#box");   
});

$("#newlevelbtn").click(function(){  
    var rows = $('#MatrixTable tr').length;
    var cols = $('#MatrixTable').find("tr:first td").length;
    var tr = []; 
    var rows_1 = 0;
    $('#MatrixTable').remove();
    mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "MatrixTable" });
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);
        for (var j = 0; j < cols+1; j++) {
            var td = $('<td>').appendTo(row);
            var sel = $('<select>').attr({ class: ["matrix"]  }).appendTo(td);
            $(arr).each(function() {
                sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
            });   
            $('</td>').appendTo(row);
        }   
        $('</tr>').appendTo(row); 
    }
    console.log("TTTTT:"+mytable.html());
    mytable.appendTo("#box");   
});
```

CSS COde:

```
table{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
table td{
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
table tr{
    height:10px;
}
```

Now, the problem is that in my approach I am clearing the table div and re-creating the table with the new dimensions. In this case I am losing the previous table data. How can I save the temporary data and reload it when creating the new table? Once all the data is selected, I need to save the selection to the DB using an AJAX call.

Another question is: I have learnt about the clone function. Can clone be used on a column also?

Comment: You don't need to - and shouldn't - update your question with the solution. Just accept the answer that's been posted which solved the issue for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of replacing the enitre `table`, add `rows` and `columns` to the existing one: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/rwacv5mn/3/

```
$("#newabilitybtn").click(function(){
    $('#MatrixTable').append($('#MatrixTable').find("tr:last").clone());
});

$("#newlevelbtn").click(function(){  
    $('#MatrixTable tr').append($("#MatrixTable tr td:last").clone());
});
```

Comment: @llpo Oksanen : Thanks you made my day. Clone is real handy.

Comment: @llpo Oksanen: Now I need to add table header to the table which I had created yesterday. Now when I try to add a column I am not able to copy the Header cell. How can I solve this? I have reached until this now: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rush2ashu/rwacv5mn/). Thanks in advance

Comment: Try  adding `$('#MatrixTable thead tr').append($("#MatrixTable thead tr th:last").clone());` to the `add level button` or something

Comment: I felt something is wrong with the HTML which I pasted in the above comment. here is the corrected one : `<table id="MatrixTable"><tbody><tr><th></th><th>Level</th></tr><tr class="class1 class2"><th>Ability</th><td><select class="matrix"><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option><option value="4">Four</option></select></td></tr></tbody></table>`. Link to DEMO : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rush2ashu/rwacv5mn/8/)

Comment: @llpo Oksanen: You are my Guru. Awesome stuff. I was trying lot of things. But never got that Idea. Thank you very much.

Comment: @llpo Oksanen: I have a new requirement on top of this assignment. The requirement is to have a search box with autocomplete in each cell. I am searching the stackoverflow but no one has a solution for the way, I have added the new row/column. Do you have any idea on how to solve that. Should I create a new question for this in stackoverflow?  I have a project deadline. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you should create a new question. Comments are meant only for detailing the answer or the question. For new problems (even in the same project) you should always create a new question. Plus, I didn't quite understand what you were trying to do this time.

Comment: @llpo Oksanen : here is the link to the new question. [ New Assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828262/how-to-add-jquery-autocomplete-ui-functionality-to-each-cell-in-my-table). Thanks.